# Forcing use of old (bluez) Bluetooth stack in Android >=4.3

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

I have an app that's exchanging data with a device using a RFCOMM channel over Bluetooth. I have found that for some reason all devices running Android 4.3 and up have degraded performance and introduce a link lag that's unacceptable (I'm displaying live data from the device).

The Bluetooth connection on Android 4.2 and older is performing fine.

Is there a way to force the device to use the BlueZ stack?

Comment: You need to build bluez in android, check [android-bluez](https://gitorious.org/android-bluez) git repo

Comment: But for this to work I need to have root on each device - i.e. there is no way to ship this as a part of an app, right?